# How do I print all prime factors of a large number (eg. 99999999) keeping in mind the performance/time and not using any special packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have written the following code.

```
import math
def check_isprime(num):
    flag=0
    if num<2:
        return False

    for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(num))+1):
        if num%i == 0:
            flag=1
            break

    if flag:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def find_prime_factors(number):
    while number != 1:
        for i in range(2,number+1):
            if check_isprime(i):
                if number%i==0:
                    print i
                    number=number/i 
                    break  
#find_prime_factors(99999999) (Not able to execute)
#find_prime_factors(10000000) (This is fine)
```

The code is working properly for many large numbers too, but failed for others as the loop is running for more number of times.
Is it possible to optimize this a little bit, or is there any better approach?

Comment: "Is it possible to optimize this a little bit," - yes, cache primes already found

Comment: @MitchWheat I couldn't find much about cache primes on the internet that i can implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be many ways, this can be solved efficiently, one of them is using primefac pacakage, if you look into this package it includes all the efficient ways to solve this:

```
import primefac
n = 100
factors = list(primefac.primefac(n))
```

Use this, unless this is your assignment, where you need to submit some logic. :)

Edit Loop Approach:

```
def get_list_primes(n):
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            factors.append(i)
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)
    return factors
```

This is working efficiently for me.

Comment: Wow! Its super super fast and amazing! Can't upvote though, because of my reputation.

Comment: No problem. Thanks.